# android (exception ActityNotFoundException)

Tags: android, activitynotfoundexception

I am working on an android game https://code.google.com/p/something-soft/ and I my log cat says that it is trying to fire the intent to the game, but then the main thread seems to die (with and ActivityNotFoundException) and then seems to freeze.

in the code repository I have submitted all files except /bin... including the most recent logcat output(/trunk/KingLand/log.txt), and debugger output(/trunk/KingLnad/debug.txt)

the emulator that I am running is Android platform 2.1-update1 with 2024MiB memmory if that can really cause any issues (I'm not sure)

any assistence would be appriciated.

edit: AndroidManifest.xml

```
$<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
$  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
$        package="android.app"
$        android:versionCode="1"
$        android:versionName="1.0">
$        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
$        <activity android:name="com.Something.Soft.KingsLand"
$                    android:label="@string/app_name">
$             <intent-filter>
$                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
$                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
$             </intent-filter>
$        </activity>
$        <activity android:name=".Tutorial"
$              android:label="@string/tutorial"
$              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"/>
$        <activity android:name=".Prefs"
$              android:label="@string/settingsTitle"/>
$        <activity android:name=".Game"     // this is the where the intent should fire to
$              android:label="@string/gameTitle"/>
$        </application>
$</manifest>
```

Comment: Is the Intent defined in the manifest file?

Comment: Is the activity defined in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: yes that is included in the manifest. question now contains manifest

Comment: MisterSquonk: no this change still causes the main thread to reach the same Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package attribute should be the package where your Activities are going to be.

In your AndroidManifest.XML, the manifest tag should declare on attribute package the package where your activities are.

It's going to be:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Something.Soft"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
 //The others attributes.
```

You defined: "package="android.app""
And your Activity are on com.Something.Soft

You should also follow the code conventions, package names are full lower-case.

Comment: in what file is this("package="android.app" to "package="com.Something.Soft")  change to be made as I am not finding it

Comment: thank you: at one point I changed the package name through (right click project>android Tools>rename Aplication Package) and I guess that it didn't change everything

Answer (score 1):

Your packages differ between the Activities.  Assuming the "com.Something.Soft." package is where your Game activity lives, change the `package="android.app"` to `package="com.Something.Soft"`.

You can alternatively explicitly spell out the full name where the activity is defined, i.e. `<activity android:name="com.Something.Soft.Game"`

Comment: in what file is this("package="android.app" to "package="com.Something.Soft") change to be made as I am not finding it

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml line 3 above.